# How to assign object values from an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've made a constructor for an object called "Book". I've captured all the values from a form in an array. Now I want to assign the values of this array to this constructor. However, I'm quite stuck because I don't seem to find what I'm looking for on Google or StackOverflow.

Here's my code:

```
let formArray = [];
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]').forEach(function (node) {
    formArray.push(node.value);
});

let newBook = new Book();
let idx = 0;
Object.keys(newBook).forEach(function (k) {
    k = formArray[idx];
})
```

However, this is my log:

```
Book {title: undefined, author: undefined, nPages: undefined, isRead: undefined}
title: undefined
author: undefined
nPages: undefined
isRead: undefined
```

Please help me figure this out!

Comment: are you sure you are getting node.value?

Comment: Yeah `formArray.push(node.value)` works as expected, `console.log(formArray)` returns: `["1", "1", "1", "1"]` (for example).

Comment: yes because its working late i answred this below

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can setup something like what you are after, I've including just two properties for simplicity.

```js
class Book {
  constructor({ title, author }) {
    this.title = title
    this.author = author
  }
}

const values = {}
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]').forEach(function (node) {
    values[node.name] = node.value
});

console.log(new Book(values))
```

```html
<input type="text" name="title" value="The Never Ending Story" />
<input type="text" name="author" value="Michael Ende" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let formArray = [];
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]').forEach(function (node) {
    formArray.push(node&&node.value);
});

let newBook = new Book();
let idx = 0;
Object.keys(newBook).forEach(function (k) {
    k = formArray[idx];
})
```

try this one i think js running code before node.value